# Mysql- how to get value from json filed

Tags: mysql, json, regex

I have a column in which form data is placed in json string how I can extract data with query. I have checked solution over internet every one suggested to apply regex. How I can apply regex to get value of `Pass Type` from below string.

```
.....{\"label\":\"Pass Type\",\"value\":\"prof_3Day\",\"identifier\":\"field102\",\"type\":\"dropdown\",\"page\":3,\"page_name\":\"Step 3\",\"options\":[{......
```

Comment: If it's JSON, why not parse it as JSON? Using a regular expression is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Use `COLUMN_NAME like '%Pass Type%'` in where condition

Comment: In 5.7 there are JSON extraction functions.

Answer (score 1):

## Forward

Because of all the possible edge cases, I don't recommend using a regex to search JSON strings. However since it sounds like you have creative control over the JSON string, then you should be able to avoid many of the edge cases that would cause a problem.

## Description

This regex will do the following:

- search for the key `label` and return the it's value
- removes the quotes from the value
- avoids the obvious edge cases when dealing with JSON strings
- I wasn't sure if you're sample text really had `\"` substrings, so this regex is written too work with or without the `\`'s

The regex:

```
\{(?:"[^"]*"|[^{}"]*|\{[^{}]*})*?"label\\?":\K"([^"]*)\\?"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Source Text**

```
.....{\"label\":\"Pass Type\",\"value\":\"prof_3Day\",\"identifier\":\"field102\",\"type\":\"dropdown\",\"page\":3,\"page_name\":\"Step 3\",\"options\":[{......
```

**Resulting Capture Groups**

- Group 0 gets the `label` and value set from the original string
- Group 1 gets just the value, with the slashes and quotes removed

**Sample Match**

```
[0] => \"Pass Type\"
[1] => Pass Type
```

## Explained

- the lead in helps avoid many of the messy edge cases
- the `\K` might not be supported so you could remove that. if it's removed then capture group 0 will contain the entire string up to the `label` keyname

**Details**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,:]                     any character of: ',', ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^{}"]*                  any character except: '{', '}', '"' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    }                        '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       'K'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\?                      '\' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "label                   '"label'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\?                      '\' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ":                       '":'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\?                      '\' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*?                   any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\?                      '\' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```